# Escape character for underscore in Ruby on Rails queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to do is to write a query like the following:

```
Foo.where("bar LIKE 'bam\_%'")
```

The idea being that this would return all the rows where bar, which contains a string, starts with 'bam_' and then is of an indeterminate length thereafter. I've tried this as a pure MySQL query in the MySQL workbench and it seems to work as expected. When I do this in RoR, however, it seems to ignore the escape character completely and treats underscore like the wildcard that it really is. Is there not a way to write this in Rails where I can include the underscore in my query? Thanks.

Comment: Your example contains a syntax error. Given that there may be other misrepresentations, can you please copy your code exactly?

Comment: Was missing the second double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character in Ruby strings, so `\_` means to treat the `_` as literal.  Since `_` is treated as literal anyway, this does nothing, except to treat the `\` as if it wasn't there.  One of the ways to actually have a backslash in your string given by a Ruby literal is to escape it by using another backslash (e.g. `"bar LIKE 'bam\\_%'"`).